# Can I reconnect history for an improperly extracted library in subversion?

Tags: svn

"Someone" has extracted

```
/giant-repo/trunk/sublib
```

into

```
/fancyname/trunk
```

Some of the directories and files were copied or moved correctly, using `svn cp` and `svn mv`, thus preserving history.

Others, both files and directories, were freshly constructed (isomorphically modulo renamings from `sublib` to `fancyname`) in the new location before file content was copied in from the original location (i.e. unversioned).

What I'm seeing is:

```
~/work/fancyname> svn log -r 1234 --verbose
...
   A /fancyname/trunk/foo.txt
   A /fancyname/trunk/bar.txt (from /giant-repo/trunk/sublib/bar.txt:950)
...
```

There are a total of about 140 files, and 100 commits to `/fancyname/trunk` at present.

Is there a way to tell subversion that `foo.txt`, that was added in `r1234`, really should have been a copy from `sublib/foo.txt:950`?

If not (and I suspect this is the case), how can I hack this into shape?
I imagine for files that haven't had any commits in the new repo, the easiest solution will be to remove the new file (is there a "super" revert that reverts the add from the repository?) and then issue a correct `svn cp`.

What about files with changes in the new repo, is there a way to "pickle" those changes, copy the file properly, then reapply the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not modify history in SVN (without dumping the repo and modifying the dumpfile, which is heavy and cumbersome work).

So the easiest(not the correct!) way is to

`svn rename foo.txt foo_wrong.txt`, then

`svn copy foo.txt@950 foo.txt` (now commit)

by this you have repaired your history for foo.txt from now on. The time in between the version history is broken. And you cannot fix it with svn client.